# Blocking Facebook mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

This may appear counter intuitive to normal posts here, but I was directed to stack overflow as the forum for questions from the FB developer site so here goes!

I'm a network engineer assisting a local school district with some network upgrades.  Part of the upgrades involved setting up a web content filter (Untangle), which works great.  For various reasons they want to block access to facebook from the school's network during normal school hours.  The normal and mobile websites are blocked, but the web content filter doesn't block the mobile app (since the requests aren't coming from a browser the traffic is analyzed differently).

I've opened a ticket with them to see if there is a work-around, but am looking for a way to block the mobile app from accessing facebook until they have a solution.  What IP/hostname/ports can I block on our Cisco ASA to stop traffic to the mobile app site?  Is there an easy check the app does for connectivity to FB that I can intercept and "trick" it into thinking it doesn't have network access?

These are personal devices, so we can't make changes to them, and yes I realize that technically they could still get access via their mobile provider.

Thanks in advance for ideas and any suggestions!

-Beaty

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. http://serverfault.com is the StackExchange site for sysadmin questions like these. I am sorry if the FB developer site members directed you to the wrong place.

Comment: It's too bad it's off topic, I think this is a pretty interesting question. Now keep in mind I have no idea what I'm talking about on this topic but would it be possible to create a temporary closed network on which there is only one device that is trying to access Facebook and look to see what servers it tries to connect to?